# SSL: Tomcat or JBoss?

Tags: tomcat, jboss, https

I actually have an application deployed on a Tomcat server but in the future I think I'll pass to JBoss.
Now I have to implement the use of https for communication and I don't know if it's better to implement it first on Tomcat or if is better to pass to JBoss first and then implement everything. Is https management so different between them? Is there any advantage in using JBoss instead of Tomcat?

Thanks

Jaxer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Tomcat already supports SSL](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/ssl-howto.html). JBoss uses under the covers a fork of Tomcat which is expanded with extra services (EJB, JMS, etc). The original Tomcat core is generally only slightly modified. You can readup the JBoss SSL HOWTO [here](http://docs.jboss.org/jbossweb/latest/ssl-howto.html), which is, as you see, not much different from Tomcat's HOWTO.

Answer (score 0):

The classical way (for me) is to use only tomcat (a lot lighter) and add a axis stack for webservices. Https is already manage by tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

Adding SSL is pretty trivial in both cases. Start with what you have.